# Wireless & Automatic photo sync from iPhone to Macos

Tags: ios, backup, photos, nas

I've got a puzzle you can hopefully help me solve. I would like to:

- automatically back up my iPhone photos to my NAS
- without using the internet (so no cloud services etc.)

iOS 13.1.2
WD EX2 Ultra
Both devices are connected to the same network

I've so far done this using the WD MyCloud app, but frankly, I don't trust its security. Too many security failures to often. Now I can backup my Macbook using TimeMachine without connecting the NAS to the www but there is no similar solution for iPhones as far as I know.

Any help would be much appreciated. Don't want to be forced to use iCloud or, god forbid, manually back-up my photos.

Comment: I can recommend Qnap NAS solutions. They have iOS app "QFile" which makes automatic backups of photos (also with LivePhoto) to NAS. You can use it in your internal network or over internet directly to your NAS without any cloud services. Next step to sync photos from NAS to MacOS - you can use QSync app for that.

Comment: @Daniel, great recommendation! Looking into it now. However this means I would have to trade in my EX2 Ultra for a QNAP right? If anyone knows a way without having to do that, it'd be much appreciated!